# How to define a function in Rust?

Tags: rust

I decided to do 2D vector cross product in Rust. In JavaScript, this is simple to do:

```js
float CrossProduct( const Vec2& a, const Vec2& b ) {
    return a.x * b.y - a.y * b.x;
}
```

I tried to convert it to the Rust system:

```
// Just created two separate variables for the two different vectors

let vec1 = vec![1.15, 7.0];
let vec2 = vec![7.0, 2.0];
let cross_product(&vec1, &vec2) = vec1[0] * vec2[1] - vec1[1] * vec2[0];
println!("{}", cross_product);

// I also tried return.
let vec1 = vec![1.15, 7.0];
let vec2 = vec![7.0, 2.0];
let cross_product(&vec1, &vec2) {
    return (vec1[0] * vec2[1] - vec1[1] * vec2[0]);
}
println!("{}", cross_product);
```

I thought that one of these would work, however this was more of a reality check to me how different Rust can be from any language I have used previously.

I found a very inefficient way to work around this, however I would rather learn to do this correctly. I am new to Rust, so please take my attempts with a grain of salt.

Comment: You haven't defined a function `cross_product` function.

Comment: Go read [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/). It is free and answers beginner questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible ways to do this.

#### First Way

You can declare a function and pass it into `println!()` which is similar to many programming languages like Java, C#,  etc.

```
// Declare the function
fn cross_product(slice1: &[i32], slice2: &[i32]) -> i32 {
    slice1[0] * slice2[1] - slice1[1] * slice2[2]
}

// Use it Like following
fn main() {
    let vec1 = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let vec2 = vec![4, 5, 6];

    println!("{}", cross_product(&vec1[..], &vec2[..]));
}
```

#### Second Way

You can declare a closure and pass it into `println!()`, a common methodology in functional programming:

```
// You can declare a closure and use it as function in the same code block
fn main() {
    let vec1 = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let vec2 = vec![4, 5, 6];

    let cross_product = |slice1: &[i32], slice2: &[i32]| -> i32 {
        let result = slice1[0] * slice2[1] - slice1[1] * slice2[2];
        result
    };

    println!("{}", cross_product(&vec1[..], &vec2[..]));
}
```

Please note that I have created the vectors and closures using the `i32` data type, which corresponds to an integer. You can change the type with `f32` or if you want wider float range `f64`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are mainly having problems with Rust syntax. You can either create a cross product function or do the cross product inline.

```
let vec1 = vec![1.15, 7.0];
let vec2 = vec![7.0, 2.0];
let cross_product = vec1[0] * vec2[1] - vec1[1] * vec2[0];
println!("{}", cross_product);
```

If you want a function you can use continually.

```
fn function_cross_product(vec1: Vec<f64>, vec2: Vec<f64>) -> f64 {
  return vec1[0] * vec2[1] - vec1[1] * vec2[0];
};
let other_product = function_cross_product(vec1, vec2);
println!("{}", other_product);
```

The second solution can be misleading because it will always produce the cross product for a 2x2 vector even if you pass different sized vectors.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Comment: Taking ownership of the vectors is *highly unlikely* to be what the OP wants.